# Linux run a child process with redirection without spawning a new process

Tags: ruby, linux, shell

I'm using ruby to start a background service. I store PID for this service to terminate it later. Let's say for simplicity I need to run the background service `"sleep 1000"`. I use this command and it works correctly

```
child_pid = fork {exec("sleep 1000")} # => 7845

ps  
7845 pts/15   00:00:00 sleep
```

`child_pid` stores PID of sleep. However, when I try to redirect the stdout to a file (for logging), it behaves differently.

```
child_pid = fork {exec("sleep 1000 > sleep.log")} # => 7829
```

In this case, `child_pid` is a PID of a sh process, and the sleep process takes another PID.

```
ps  
7829 pts/15   00:00:00 sh  
7832 pts/15   00:00:00 sleep
```

Any explanations for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a simple command, it can be run directly.  Redirections (and environment variables, and `;` and pipes and a number of other things) are not simple commands; they are shell syntax, therefore Ruby starts a shell to process them.  If you want to avoid this, you need to do the redirection in Ruby in the `fork`ed child process before the `exec`, by reopening standard output on the redirection file.